# Binary Tree In Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

A binary tree can be defined in terms of 2 predicates:

- `emptyBT`, the empty binary tree.
- `BTTree(N,T1,T2)` that is true if `N` is the root of a binary tree with left subtree `T1` and right subtree `T2`, where all the items in `T1` are less than or equal to `N` and all the items in `T2` are greater than `N`.

Write a Prolog program that implements the following predicates:

- `insert(I,T1,T2)` is true if `T2` is the binary tree resulting from I being inserted into binary tree `T1`.
- `preorder(T,L)` is true if `L` is a list of nodes generated by a preorder traversal of the binary tree `T`.
- `inorder(T,L)` is true if `L` is a list of nodes generated by a inorder traversal of the binary tree `T`.
- `postorder(T,L)` is true if `L` is a list of nodes generated by a postorder traversal of the binary tree `T`.
- `search(T,I)` is true if `I` is contained in the binary tree `T`.
- `height(T,H)` is true if `H` is the height of the binary tree `T`. An empty tree has height `0` and a tree with one item has height `1`.

---

Here's my code so far: I have no idea if its right, any help or pointers would 
be greatly appreciated!

```
isempty(nil) :- !.
isempty(tree(nil,nil,nil)).

bTTree(tree(_,nil,nil)).
bTTree(tree(N,Left,nil)) :- Left@=<N.
bTTree(tree(N,nil,Right)) :- N@<Right.
bTTree(tree(_,Left,Right)) :- bTTree(Left), bTTree(Right).
bTTree(tree(N,Left,Right)) :- Left@=<N, N@<Right.

%traversals.
%preorder -- N,Left,Right

preorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t),
bTTree(t(N,Left,Right)),
append(N,[Left|Right],L).
preorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(_,Left,_),
preorder(Left,L).
preorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(_,_,Right),
preorder(Right,L).


%inorder -- Left,N,Right.

inorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t),
bTTree(t(N,Left,Right)),
append(Left,[N|Right],L).
inorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(N,_,_)), inorder(N,L).
inorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(_,_,Right)), inorder(Right,L).


%postorder -- Left,Right,N

postorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t),
bTTree(t(N,Left,Right)),
append(Left,[Right|N],L).
postorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(_,_,Right)),
inorder(Right,L).
postorder(t,L) :- bTTree(t(N,_,_)),
append(_,[_|N],L).

search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(I,_,_)). %searches each node for I
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,I,_)).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,_,I)).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,N,_)), search(N,I).%recursive method to search left branch for I
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,_,N)), search(N,I).%recursive  " " " right branch for I

height(t,H) :- bTTree(t(nil,nil,nil)), H is 0.   %height of empty tree is 0
height(t,H) :- bTTree(t(_,nil,nil)), H is 1.     %height of single node Btree is 1
height(t,H) :-
   bTTree(t(_,Left,Right)),  %otherwise height of bTree is the max
   height(Left, H1),     %height of left or right branch plus 1
   height(Right, H2),
   H is max(H1,H2) + 1.

insert(I,t1,t2) :-
   bTTree(t1(X,L,_)),
   bTTree(t2(X,L,I)).
insert(I,t1,t2) :-
   bTTree(t1(nil,nil,nil)),
   bTTree(t2(I,nil,nil)).
insert(I,t1,t2) :-
   bTTree(t1(X,L,_)),
   bTTree(t2(X,L,I)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, I think that your code cannot work, and doesn't show any useful coding practice. Then I implemented using a compact notation, where `-` it's the empty tree, and a tree is `t(LeftSubtree, Int, RightSubtree)`. As required, all ints in LeftSubtree are less than Int, etc...

```
ins(I, -, t(-, I, -)).
ins(I, t(L, X, R), t(P, Y, Q)) :-
    (   I < X
    ->  ins(I, L, U),
        (P, Y, Q) = (U, X, R)
    ;   I > X
    ->  ins(I, R, U),
        (P, Y, Q) = (L, X, U)
    ;   (P, Y, Q) = (L, X, R)  % already in, nothing to do
    ).

inl([N|Ns], T0, T) :-
    ins(N, T0, T1),
    inl(Ns, T1, T).
inl([], T, T).
```

inl/3 it's an utility that insert all the ints in a tree and 'returns' the result.
Some test:

```
inl([3,6,1],-,X).
X = t(t(-, 1, -), 3, t(-, 6, -)) ;
false.

?- inl([3,6,1,1],-,X).
X = t(t(-, 1, -), 3, t(-, 6, -)) .

?- inl([3,6,1,1,4],-,X).
X = t(t(-, 1, -), 3, t(t(-, 4, -), 6, -)) ;
false.
```

Comment: I haven't looked at prolog in quite a while very rusty. Does your answer work? Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide an answer that works as same as @CapelliC, but with an explanation and probably a friendly code.

```
% it is true when X is greater than Y
gt(X,Y):- X > Y.

% create a node with only X
% createnode(+Tree, +Value, -t (-Value, -LeftLeaf, -RightLeaf))
createnode(nil, X ,t(X, nil ,nil)).

% base case
% avoid the duplicate
% otherwise, create a node
createnode(t(X, Left, Right), X, t(X, Left, Right)):-!. % the "!" cut down the backtracking, it's often more efficient

% create a node to a tree with the value X
% if X is smaller, create a node, with the value X, to Left1 subtree
% which backtracks to the base case
createnode(t(Root, Left, Right), X, t(Root, Left1, Right)):-
  gt(Root, X),!,
  createnode(Left, X, Left1).

createnode(t(Root, Left, Right), X, t(Root, Left, Right1)):-
  gt(X, Root),!,
  createnode(Right, X, Right1).

% base case
% the NewTree equals the Result tree
% and the list is empty, then the backtracking stops
insertnode([],Tree,Tree).

% insert a list of tree node
insertnode([X|Xs], Tree, Result):-
  createnode(Tree, X, NewTree),
  insertnode(Xs, NewTree, Result).
```

The queries:

```
?-insertnode([7,6,12],nil,Tree).
Tree = t(7, t(6, nil, nil), t(12, nil, nil)).

?- createnode(nil,7,T1),createnode(T1,12,T2),createnode(T2,6,T3)
T1 = t(7, nil, nil),
T2 = t(7, nil, t(12, nil, nil)),
T3 = t(7, t(6, nil, nil), t(12, nil, nil)).
```